Palau Jellyfish Lake - are there still jellyfish?
Planning to visit Palau soon. The Jellyfish Lake seems to be a highlight, but saw recent reports that almost all jellyfish are now gone.
If you've been there recently, please let me know the jellyfish situation. Can you still see a lot of them?

Relevant Jellyfish die-off

What is "worthwhile" to the OP may not be "worthwhile" to others. This seems a classica "opinion" question. I voted to close.

@DavidRecallsMonica Technically it could be considered an opinion, but the OP is looking at a tourist attraction that is dependent on the animals actually existing.  But as per the link I posted and the reports the OP read, while the lake may still exist, it is possible that the actually attraction doesn't.  And the OP is trying to determine if the attraction still does exist.

@DavidRecallsMonica the OP lays out the clear criteria (are there still jellyfish in the lake?) that they want to use to evaluate if a trip would be worthwhile for them. This is answerable.

@mlc I disagree. It's unclear to me if it'd be worthwhile (in the OP's view) if only some of the jellyfish remained. The OP asks about "the jellyfish situation" and if seeing the lake is worthwhile. It's still a matter of opinion.

Similar question about a different animal, which has remained open:  How many cats are there on "Cat Island" Aoshima, Japan these days? Still a destination for "cat tourists" after the 2018 population control measures?

@DavidRecallsMonica Then treat it as an XY problem and answer what the current vs historical jellyfish density is for that lake.  That would give the OP the metrics they need to make their decision.

OP here. Seeing the discussion about my question, wanted to clarify what I'm after. I've seen pictures of people swimming through massive and dense groups of yellow jellyfish, like this: https://www.atlasobscura.com/places/jellyfish-lake. That looked like a fun and unique experience. However, then I read reports that there are only a few left. I wouldn't spend the money to go swimming in a lake with only a few jellyfish - the attraction is the numbers and density. So what I want to know is: does the lake have massive dense groups of jellyfish, like shown on the linked page?

Thanks for the clarity. Your question — as amended to "Does the lake have massive dense groups of jellyfish as shown on the linked page — is clearly answerable, and not opinion. Please edit your question text (using the "edit" button below the question) to reflect this new phrasing. With the new phrasing, I agree won't asked for opinion and I'll withdraw my close vote.
